# include/eval perl file into unique namespace defined at runtime

Tags: perl

I'm writing a tool that must import a number of other perl config files.  The files are not wrapped w/packages and may have similar or conflicting variables/functions.  I don't have the ability to change the format of these files, so I must work around what they are.  What I was thinking to do was import each into a unique name space, but I've not found a way to do that using `do`, `require`, or `use`.  If I don't use dynamic names, just a hardcoded name, I can do it.

Want something like this:

```
sub sourceTheFile {
  my ($namespace, $file) = @_;
  package $namespace;
  do $file;
  1;
  return;
}
```

That doesn't work because the package command requires a constant for the name.  So then I try something like this:

```
sub sourceTheFile {
  my ($namespace, $file) = @_;
  eval "package $namespace;do $file;1;"
  return;
}
```

But the contents of the file read by `do` are placed in the `main::` scope not the one I want. The target scope is created, just not populated by the 
`do`. (I tried require, and just a straight `cat $file` inside the eval as well.)

I'm using `Devel::Symdump` to verify that the namespaces are built correctly or not.

example input file:

```
my $xyz = "some var";
%all_have_this = ( common=>"stuff" );
```

**ADDITIONAL CHALLENGE**

Using the answer that does the temp file build and do call, I can make this work dynamically as I require.  BUT, big but, how do I now reference the data inside this new namespace? Perl doesn't seem to have the lose ability to build a variable name from a string and use that as the variable.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It is a little more up front work, but using a hook in `@INC` would be a more robust way to do this.

Comment: You realize if you have `my $xyz = '...'` and you put that in a package, you cannot access it from outside the package, right?

Comment: @SinanÜnür - yes, I know the my vars will not be accessible.  The unqualified vars (no my/our/local) are the ones I really want.

Comment: Would this not be better if the configuration were data rather than code?

Comment: @Ed. As I mentioned, I can't change the format of the input files.  And there are huge advantages gained by them being perl.

Comment: Fair enough, you know your situation better than I do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why the `eval` did not work. Maybe a bug? Here is a workaround using a temp file. This works for me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Devel::Symdump;
use File::Temp;

my $file = './test.pl';
my $namespace = 'TEST';
{
    my $fh = File::Temp->new();
    print $fh "package $namespace;\n";
    print $fh "do '$file';\n";
    print $fh "1;\n";
    close $fh;
    do $fh->filename;
}
```

Comment: So far this seems the most dynamic option (can be done on the fly as more data is read in).

Answer (score 3):

Perl's [`use`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) and [`require`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) facilities make use of any hooks you might have installed in `@INC`. You can simply install a hook which looks in a specific location to load modules with a prefix you choose:

```
package MyIncHook;

use strict;
use warnings;

use autouse Carp => qw( croak );

use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile );

sub import {
    my ($class, $prefix, $location) = @_;
    unshift @INC, _loader_for($prefix, $location);
    return;
}

sub _loader_for {
    my $prefix = shift;
    my $location = shift;

    $prefix =~ s{::}{/}g;

    return sub {
        my $self = shift;
        my $wanted = shift;

        return unless $wanted =~ /^\Q$prefix/;

        my $path = catfile($location, $wanted);
        my ($is_done);

        open my $fh, '<', $path
            or croak "Failed to open '$path' for reading: $!";

        my $loader = sub {
            if ($is_done) {
                close $fh
                    or croak "Failed to close '$path': $!";
                return 0;
            }
            if (defined (my $line = <$fh>)) {
                $_ = $line;
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                $_ = "1\n";
                $is_done = 1;
                return 1;
            }
        };

        (my $package = $wanted) =~ s{/}{::}g;
        $package =~ s/[.]pm\z//;

        my @ret = (\"package $package;", $loader);
        return @ret;
    }
}

__PACKAGE__;
__END__
```

Obviously, modify the construction of `$path` according to your requirements.

You can use it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use MyIncHook ('My::Namespace', "$ENV{TEMP}/1");

use My::Namespace::Rand;

print $My::Namespace::Rand::settings{WARNING_LEVEL}, "\n";
```

where `$ENV{TEMP}/1/My/Namespace/Rand.pm` contains:

```
%settings = (
    WARNING_LEVEL => 'critical',
);
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> perl t.pl
critical
```

You can, obviously, define your own mapping from made up module names to file names.

Comment: Interesting answer. Not sure I understood the sentence *"... because it is the `do` that is looking for the true value at the end of `$file`"*. Why is `do` looking for a true value, isn't it `require` that should be looking for a true value? According to the documentation: `do EXPR` only executes the content of the filename `EXPR` as a Perl script.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thank you for the observation. I removed that part from my answer. It is possible that there is another problem with the code the OP is not showing us.

Comment: How would you make this more dynamic?  I start with a list of files to read (command line).  As I parse that list, those files may reference others (as file paths in strings) that I have to dynamically read in as well.